# Cannot Get Successful Session to a Website That Requires my Login - Request Lib in Python

Tags: python, rest, session, python-requests

I'm currently working on attempting to scrape some HTML files from an electronic medical system that I use for work. I currently have a python bot that logs into the system and is able to download and send faxes for me, but there's some pages I want my bot to quickly grab before it even is logged in and sending faxes. These pages are basic HTML that have extremely predictable URLs and I have tested I can manually call the pages from my browser, so once I do get my session established it should be easy work.

The website is: https://kinnser.net/

Login URL: https://kinnser.net/login.cfm

second URL: https://kinnser.net/AM/Message/inbox.cfm

```
     import requests
     import json
     import logging
     import json
     from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
     from lxml import html

     #This URL will be the URL that your login form points to with the "action" tag.
     POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://kinnser.net/loginlogic.cfm'

     #This URL is the page you actually want to pull down with requests.
     REQUEST_URL = 'https://kinnser.net/AM/Message/inbox.cfm'

     #username-input-name is the "name" tag associated with the username input field of the login form.
     #password-input-name is the "name" tag associated with the password input field of the login form.
     payload = {
         'username': 'XXXXXXXX',
         'password': 'XXXXXXXXX'}

     headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}
     with requests.Session() as session:
         post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers=headers)
         print(post)
         r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
         print(r.text)   #or whatever else you want to do with the request data!
```

I played around with the username, & password field by setting them equal to the input's name/ID but that wouldn't work. So I tried this script on our old EMR we used just to confirm it wasn't broken, and it did indeed work perfectly. So I began to play around with the headers in my request and it was still no dice. I'm not sure if my login is just failing or if they're detecting me being a bot and serving me the login page over and over again but I have spent about 10 hours trying to research a solution and I've hit a wall with my project currently.

If anyone see's any mistakes in my code or has workable solutions please feel free to suggest them. Thanks for the help and hopefully I'll soon grow to understand more about RESTful web services.

Comment: https://kinnser.net/loginlogic.cfm
This is post url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the HTML might actually be in `post.text`?

edit:
try the request with these headers:

```py
...
user_agent_str = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " \
                 + "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " \
                 + "Chrome/78.0.3904.97 " \
                 + "Safari/537.36"

content_type_str = "application/json"

headers = {
    "user-agent": user_agent_str,
    "content-type": content_type_str
}
...
```

Another edit:

I'm not sure if `requests` already handles this, but payload isn't valid JSON.  You might also try using double instead of single quotes.

Comment: post.text and r.text will return the same exact HTML currently which is from the login page. I just removed .text to make running it and reading the output easier.

Comment: The User-Agent you set up in that code snippet was the answer! Now it's running and I'm scraping any page I want in the session, thank you so much!!! Now I can really dive in! :D

Comment: Sure thing ... I mean 200 OK :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying out this two things.

- `kinnser.net/loginlogic.cfm` From network calls it looks like this is post url.
- Change 'Username' to 'username' and 'Password' to 'password' and try.

Since I don't have access username and password i can not verify this but this two thing might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! 

Okay I made updates to the script to reflect these issues. I'm going to update the post as well, but I'm still unfortunately getting served the login page. If I were to pass you a sandbox login to a mock system could you possibly help me determine the rest of the issues? Do you think it's headers now or something?